# Parameters in a non-parametric model

Tags: self-study, references, nonparametric, parameterization

I have not understood this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_statistics) statement:

> The difference between parametric model and non-parametric model is that the former has a fixed number of parameters, while the latter grows the number of parameters with the amount of training data.

*How does the number of parameters in a non-parametric model increase with the amount of training data?*

Comment: Hi. Did you get to see a practical implementation of this, where number of parameters are growing with new incoming data? It would be a huge help if you could point me to such a source. I have just started nonparametrics(HDP) and am struggling with relating the theory to practical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nonparametric methods don't specify something (maybe the distribution, maybe a relationship between two variables*) with a fixed finite number of parameters; they're (potentially) infinite parametric.

Consider a loess curve (a form of nonparametric regression), for example; the parameters not only aren't explicit, if you attempt to count them, the number isn't even an integer.

On the other hand, you never need more than $n$ parameters to define $n$ observations; presumably in at least that sense* the number of parameters grows as you increase $n$.

Consider, for example, a kernel density estimate using the usual AIMSE-optimal bandwidth selection; that has an effective number of parameters (e.g. as measured by Ye's generalized degrees of freedom) that grows as $n$ increases (but not in proportion to $n$).

However, since the statement is referenced (*Murphy, Kevin (2012). Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective. MIT*), you should probably consult that work for the complete context.

* the second can also be regarded as not specifying something about the distribution, such as the functional form of a conditional mean

**(though in other senses as well)

Comment: I have been just introduced with non-parametric. In non-parametric method , is there any way to understand when only $1$  parameter is enough and when i need more than one parameter(2,3,etc) ?

Comment: I wouldn't read too much into the statement, nor worry over much about precisely how many parameters are required in any particular situation. The model is (at least potentially) infinite-parametric -- but these parameters - outside of the ones you're immediately testing, if any - need not be (and usually aren't) explicit.

Comment: Consider, for example, a Kolmogorov-Smirnov two sample test. No explicit parameters are involved. It doesn't matter whether the sample sizes are (10,15) or (85,120) -- the test works the same both times; the test statistic is the largest difference in ECDFs and while the model *could* be regarded as having $n_1+n_2$ parameters in that particular instance, that's of no particular interest.

Comment: It is written that `in a parametric model all the parameters are in finite-dimensional parameter spaces.` What do they mean by finite-dimensional parameter spaces? In normal distribution, $-\infty<\mu<\infty$. It doesn't range finitely.

Comment: It's not the domains of the parameters, but the dimension of the parameter vector itself. In the case of a univariate normal, the parameter vector is $(\mu,\sigma)^\top$, which is a vector of dimension 2. The boundedness or unboundedness of the values $\mu$ or $\sigma$ can take aren't under consideration.